# Using Observer as an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I am just confused with Angular's observables and subjects. I already did search for similar questions but did not find a proper answer to my need.

Let's say that I have an observable type variable that listens to data changes in Firestore and saves the changes, like this:

```js
export class AcademyProvider {

  public currentAcademy: Observable < any > ;
  private db: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private accountProvider: AccountProvider) {
    this.db = firebase.firestore();
  }
  //This method gets the details of the current logged academy
  getCurrentAcademy(academyID): Promise < any > {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.collection("academy").where("id", "==", academyID).onSnapshot(
        (academy) => {
          if (!academy.empty) {
            this.currentAcademy = academy.docs[0].data();
            console.log(this.currentAcademy);
            resolve(academy.docs[0].data());
          } else {
            //academy does not exist
            reject(false);
          }
        },
        //academy error
        (error) => {
          reject(error);
        })

    });
  }
}
```

Now what I want is to listen to the variable currentAcademy changes from different pages, like say players or settings page, using the same AcademyProvider.
What I mean is, I want to use the currentAcademy variable as both an observer to the Firestore changes (which is currently done by the above code), as well as an observable that other pages' components listen to.

Is that possible? I came across some tutorials using Subject type, but I couldn't have it working with my code.

Note: I know that I can grab the values of currentAcademy variable from other pages like this: AcademyProvider.currentAcademy['FieldName'] or so, but this does not always assure that the returned value is the latest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Subject` if you don't care about getting the value when you initialize your observing, use a `BehaviorSubject` if you want to receive a value when you first subscribe to the observer.

```
public currentAcademy: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public currentAcademy: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

In your subscription, when you get the data, transfer it to your subject :

```
this.currentAcademy.next(academy.docs[0].data());
```

In your components, you can now subscribe to this observer :

```
this.myService.currentAcademy.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: It is still not working, in the components it always say that the data is not defined.

Comment: Then you have an issue when you fetch your data.

Comment: No, I am actually fetching data correctly in the provider with the above code. But I cannot transfer this data to other component with your code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't believe you. This is supposed to work. If it doesn't, then please make an [mcve] with mocked data to prove it.